# Handling Multiple Ckeditor instance on single page

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

I have generated multiple ckeditor instances based on my ajax data and destroy the instance on demand as like below

```
 for (var i in CKEDITOR.instances) 
            try{
                CKEDITOR.instances[i].destroy();
            }catch(e){
                 CKEDITOR.instances[i] = null;
            }
 }
```

I have generated editor using loop with given value.Look at [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3xjIC3PYVNwyvXf9YtV7?p=preview)

Basically I need to show all editor once page is loaded based on ajax data. So When my data is huge, creating multiple instance which then consume browser memory.

Initiating editor on demand is not my requirement.How do i show editor as well as considering browser memory once page loaded? Please advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I would use lightweight [inline editor instances](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_inline). Create them on demand to save time and improve performance ([plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/09BRlnM4uDH56MtlJIOX?p=preview)):

```
// http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-cfg-disableAutoInline
CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;

function generateEditor( i ) {
  return CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml( '<div contenteditable="true" id="editor' + i + '"></div>' );
}

$(function() {
  var holder = CKEDITOR.document.getById( 'holder' ),
      el;

  for ( var editor = 100; editor--; ) {
    el = generateEditor( editor );
    holder.append( el );

    el.once( 'click', function() {
      CKEDITOR.inline( this );
    } );
  }

  console.log( CKEDITOR.instances );
});
```

Also:

- Make sure you use the smallest subset of plugins possible to improve performance. The [basic package](http://ckeditor.com/download) is a good starting point but also take a look on [builder](http://ckeditor.com/builder).

Comment: Thanks.I will take a look..Mean while I have used setTimeout. Please have look at http://plnkr.co/edit/LnXpIMSwNCWBufltO839?p=preview. Is it right way of doing???

Comment: "Mean while I have used setTimeout." – What for?

Comment: I would say mean time not while :) ...Initiate editor based on timeout to prevent the browser memory load usage!!! I dont know this could prevent....just tried....